# Warum sagt man „mit Präsident“ (ohne n-Deklination), aber „mit dem Präsidenten" und „für Herrn“ (beide flektiert)?

Tags: preposition, weak-declension

Soweit ich es vom Lesen erfahre heißt es

> „…und vor allem durch **den DFB-Präsidenten** Reinhard Grindel. Nach meinem Bild **mit Präsident** Erdoğan wurde ich von Joachim Löw gebeten…“ (ohne n-Deklination). Quelle: [taz](https://www.taz.de/Mesut-Oezil-rechnet-ab/!5523135)

Dieser Satz zeigt, *Präsident* als beides, flektiert und unflektiert. 
Man könnte denken, dass es an dem Artikel liegt (ob Dativ oder Akkusativ spielt hier eher keine Rolle). Aber wiederum schreibt man:

> „für Herrn“ (also, ohne Artikel, mit Flektion)

Welche Regel steckt hier?

Comment: Can you please give examples where you read the first quote? Is it in conjunction with a name or stand-alone? What was the verb used?

Comment: ah ok, then "Präsident Erdogan" is used as the full name of the object, and names are not reflected to the dativ or akkusativ form. It's "mit Dir" and "für Dich", but simply "mit Susanne" and "für Susanne".

Comment: Regarding your latest edit ("durch den DFB-Präsidenten Reinhard Grindel" vs. "Bild mit Präsident Erdoğan"): The first is a subordinate clause adding more information to the possibly unfamiliar name, as in "durch Reinhard Gründel, den Präsidenten des DFB und viermaligen Olympiasieger...". The second use is a title which is "hard-glued" to the name, "Präsident Erdogan", "Dr. Emmett Brown", "Professor Schrödinger", ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Präsident ist nicht gleich Präsident.

- **durch den DFB-Präsidenten Reinhard Grindel**

Hier gehören "Präsident" und der Name "Reinhard Grindel" nicht zusammen. Man kann das sichtbar machen, indem man ein Wort einfügt:

> durch den DFB-Präsidenten namens Reinhard Grindel

Beachte dabei auch den Artikel "den"! Im folgenden Beispiel fehlt der Artikel:

- **mit Präsident Erdoğan**

Hier ist "Präsident" ein Teil des Namens. Der Mann *heißt* Präsident Erdogan, denn Titel sind Namensbestandteile.

Anders wäre es, würdest du die Tätigkeit von Erdogan bezeichnen (und den Artikel einfügen):

> mit dem Präsident**en** Erdogan

Streicht man dagegen den Artikel bei Grindel und macht aus dem DFB-Präsidenten einen Titel, entfällt die Flexion:

> durch DFB-Präsident Grindel

Comment: Wie wäre es mit *Herr*? *Mit dem Herrn Erdogan* (anderem gleichnamigen) und *mit Herrn Erdogan*? Da hätten Herr und Präsident nicht die gleiche syntaktische Stufung.

Comment: @c.p. "Herr" ist in beiden Fällen eine Anrede und verliert diese Bedeutung nicht durch den Artikel. Der Artikel hat bei "mit dem Herrn Erdogan" eine ironisierende Wirkung. Anders wäre es beim Herrn eines Sklaven: "Er kniet vor seinem Herrn" und "Er kniet vor Herr X".

Comment: Wirklich interessant. Wie man das Nomen je nach Bedeutung beugt!

Comment: @c.p. Nein, nicht je nach Bedeutung, sondern je nach syntaktischer Funktion. Einmal ist Präsident Teil der Nominalphrase "Präsident Erdogan", das andere Mal steht "DFB-Präsident" unabhängig von "Reinhard Grindel". Die Bedeutung ist in beiden Fällen die gleiche. Man könnte auch mit Erdogan den Grindel-Satz bilden: "durch den türkischen Präsidenten Erdogan". Die Bedeutung von "Präsident" ändert sich dadurch nicht.

Answer (score 2):

In general, "mit" requires Dativ and "für" requires Akkusativ. This is where you get the second and third quote you provided.

For your first quote, I have trouble coming up with examples where this may be correct. Maybe if used together with a name, as in "er telefoniert regelmäßig mit Präsident Putin" (names are not reflected to Dativ/Akkusativ forms) or when using the title as a subject in a humoristic enumeration, as is "und das Schiff versank mit Präsident, Kapitän und Edelmann gleichermaßen, ohne Rücksicht auf deren gehobenen Stand, der doch ein Untergehen ungehörig erscheinen lässt".

Sorry, I'm not a linguist, so this is purely from the perspective of a native speaker.

Comment: But, wouldn't you say "er telefoniert regelmäßig *mit dem Präsidenten* ..."?

Comment: yes, "mit dem Präsidenten", but not "mit dem Präsidenten Putin".

Comment: Oh... I am terribly confused :) Because it should be correct e.g. "Russland unter *den Präsident**en** Putin und Medwedew*, Bundeszentrale für politische Bildung, 6. Juli 2012"

Comment: Haha, but this is plural, not Dativ/Akkusativ. "unter den Präsidenten Putin und Medwedew" = "unter Präsident Putin und Präsident Medwedew". See, it's easy ;)